# Filter param value(name value) is not sending in Ajax call

Tags: ajax, extjs, filter, extjs4, extjs-grid

Filter parameter value i.e name value is not included when i was performing filter operation in my API call as written below

```
_dc:1427270031651
counrtyId:2
custId:1
id:
name:
page:1
start:0
limit:10
sort:[{"property" : "id", "direction" : "desc"}]
```

This is my store

```
Ext.define('MyDesktop.store.DirectoriesStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:'MyDesktop.model.DirectoriesNumberModel',
    model: 'MyDesktop.model.DirectoriesModel',
    storeId:'DirectoriesStore',
    autoLoad : {
        params : {
            start : 0,
            limit : '10'
        }
    },
    pageSize : 10,
    remoteSort : true,
    sorters : [{
        property : 'id',
        direction : 'desc'
    }],
    remoteFilter : true,
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'./configuration/directory/get',
        reader:{
             type: 'json',
             root: 'data',
             totalProperty: 'total'
        },
        extraParams: {
            'countryId':    '',
            'custId':  ''
        }
     },
    autoLoad:false
});
```

and this is my view

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
]);

var filters = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    local: true,
    features: [{type: 'integer',dataIndex: 'name'},
               {type: 'string',dataIndex: 'description'},
               {type: 'string',dataIndex: 'fileName'}]
            };
```

and I added it grid as follows:

```
features: [filters],
```

Filters are working but In API call filters are not calling

Please anyone help me.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Here filter param is not sending                                _dc:1427270031651
nodeId:2
operatorId:1
id:
name:
page:1
start:0
limit:10
sort:[{"property":"id","direction":"desc"}]

Comment: A good place to start would be http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks Raw for ur reply... Problem is sending params or filters with ajax proxy in this Filter param is missing

Answer (score 0):

You have remote filtering disabled in your store.

Change `remoteFilter: false` to `remoteFilter: true` and try again.

From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-cfg-remoteFilter):

> remoteFilter : Boolean
>
> true to defer any filtering operation to the server. If false,
>   filtering is done locally on the client.

It also appears that your specifically telling your application to apply the filters locally with the `local:true` config.

Comment: after making true also filter params are not sending in the ajax call
Query String Parameters
id:
name:
page:1
start:0
limit:10
sort:[{"property":"id","direction":"desc"}]

Comment: can you provide a fiddle at fiddle.sencha.com and I will investigate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the params are not being sent to the ajax call. But hey, try changing the page after you loaded your store. Then try sorting again. You will see that the params are now being sent along in the Ajax request.

My current workaround is to imitate a changepage via `gridStore.loadPage(page, [options])`. You should also change it back to first page again after that.

After you change the page, sort will be working for all following requests.

This of course is just a workaround and we may have different requirements. My grid is calling `store.load()` after render so I attached the change page there.

Hope you have some hints.

**NOTE: THIS IS ONLY A WORKAROUND!**